# Handle stream like maybe monad

Tags: javascript, haskell, rxjs5

Consider following stream:

```
 const oEmailValid$ = oEmailInput$
      .map(_catchInputCtrlValue)
      .map(_isStringNotEmpty) 
      .map(...)
      .map(...)
      .map(...)
      .map(...)
      .subscribe((predicate) => console.log(predicate))
```

Suppose `_isStringNotEmpty` returns `false`, so I wan't to continue the stream but still want to receive on the subscribe function the returned value of `_isStringNotEmpty`, in this case is `false`.

How to get it?

To clarify, what I mean, consider the following `Haskell` code:

```
(Just 3) >>= (\_ -> Just 4) >>= (\_ -> Just 7) >>= (\_ -> Nothing) >>= (\_ -> Just 10)
```

As the result I've got `Nothing`, because the 4th computation returns `Nothing`.

Comment: Commenting on the Haskell, it really should be `Just 3 >> Just 4 >> Just 7 >> Nothing >> ...` etc, since `>>` is defined as `a >> b = a >>= \_ -> b`.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not have pipe or compose operators so the syntax of composing functions could be:

```
compose(arrayOfFunctions);
```

Here is what compose could look like with some examples:

```
const NOTHING = {};
//see if x is like a promise (has a "then" method)
const promiseLike =
  x =>
    (x!==undefined && typeof x.then === "function")
;
/**
 * 
 * takes a function fn and returns a function that takes x
 * and calls fn(x) if x does not equal NOTHING
 * if x does equal NOTHING it returns NOTHING 
 */
const wrapMaybe = 
  fn =>
  x =>
      (promiseLike(x))   
        ?x.then(wrapMaybe(fn))
        :(x === NOTHING)?NOTHING:fn(x)
;
/**
 * 
 * takes 2 functions and turns it into:
 * fn2(fn1(x)) when a value x is provided
 * if x is a promse it will turn it into:
 * x.then(x => fn2(fn1(x)))
 * if fn1(x) is a promise it will turn it into:
 * fn1(x).then(x => fn2(x))
 * if both x and fn1(x) are promises:
 * x.then(x => fn1(x)).then(x => fn2(x))
 */
const compose2 =
  fn1=>
  fn2=>
  x => {
    //if the current value is a promise
    if(promiseLike(x)){
      return x.then(x => compose2(fn1)(fn2))
    }
    const res1 = fn1(x);
    if(promiseLike(res1)){
      //result of fn1(x) is a promise
      //  invoke fn2 with the promise resolved value
      return res1.then(x => fn2(x))
    }
    //no promise, invoke fn2 with result of fn1(x)
    return fn2(res1);

  }
;
/**
 * turns an array of functions [fn1,fn2,fn3] into:
 * fn3(fn2(fn3(x)))
 * both x or any of the results of the functions can be a promise
 * If it is a promse then the next function will be called with
 * the resolve value of the promise.
 * If the promse is rejected the next function is not called
 * the handler for reject is called later down the promise chain
 * for example fn2 returns a rejected promise:
 * fn1(x)
 * .then(x => fn2(x))
 * .then(notCalled => fn3(notcalled))
 * .then(undefined,called)
 */
const compose =
  fns =>
    fns.reduce(
      (acc,fn) => compose2(acc)(fn)
      ,x=>x//id function
    )
;
/**
 * Turns an array of functions into compose(arrOfFunctions)
 * but maps the functions to wrapMaybe(function):
 * fn turns into wrapMaybe(fn)
 */
const composeWithMaybe =
    fns =>
      compose(
        fns.map(fn=>wrapMaybe(fn))
      )
;
const source = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5]);
const mapHandlers = 
  [
    val => console.log("map:",1,"value:",val) || val + 10
    // you can return a promise in the function(s)
    //  from then on all results will be promises but next
    //  function is not called with the promise but it's resolve value
    // ,val => console.log("map:",2,"value:",val) || Promise.resolve(NOTHING)
    ,val => console.log("map:",2,"value:",val) || NOTHING
    // instead of Some or None you could return a rejected promise
    //  this basically gets you the same thing, none of the other
    //  functions are called, the result is a promise value that
    //  will invoke it's reject handler
    // ,val => console.log("map:",2,"value:",val) || Promise.reject("Rejected reason")
    ,val => console.error("map should not be executed:",3,"value:",val) || val + 10
  ]
;
const example = source
  .map(
    composeWithMaybe(
      mapHandlers
    )
  )
;
//synch example
example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));

// asynch example, you need to return a promise in one of the funcitons
// example.subscribe(
//   val => val.then(
//     val => console.log(val)
//     ,reject => console.warn(reject)
//   )
// );
```

If you want to use custom operators you can compile your code with [sweet.js](http://www.sweetjs.org/doc/tutorial.html#sweet-operators). These custom operators show up as syntax errors in your IDE so if you want to program functional then maybe have a look at [ELM](http://elm-lang.org/) or [Fable](http://fable.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Folktale has a good Maybe monad.
https://github.com/folktale/data.maybe

```
function find(collection, predicate) {

  for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; ++i) {
    var item = collection[i]
    if (predicate(item))  return Maybe.Just(item)
  }
  return Maybe.Nothing()
}

var numbers = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
var a = find(numbers, function(a){ return a > 5 })
var b = find(numbers, function(a){ return a === 0 })

a.map(function(x){ return x + 1 })
// => Maybe.Nothing
b.map(function(x){ return x + 1 })
// => Maybe.Just(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to hack it like this:

```
const NOTHING = {};
const wrapMaybe = 
  fn =>
  x =>
    (x!==undefined && typeof x.then === "function")
      ?x.then(wrapMaybe(fn))
      :(x === NOTHING)?NOTHING:fn(x)

const source = Rx.Observable.from([1,2,3,4,5]);
//wrap each map function in a maybe
const example = source
  .map(wrapMaybe(val => console.log("map:",1,val) || val + 10))
  .map(wrapMaybe(val => console.log("map:",2,val) || Promise.resolve(NOTHING)))
  .map(wrapMaybe(val => console.log("map:",3,val) || val + 10))
;
//wrap the source in an object that has mm (maybe map) function
const wrapSource =
  source => {
    source.mm = 
      function(fn){
        var ret = this.map(wrapMaybe(fn));
        ret.mm = this.mm;
        return ret;
      }
    ;
    return source;
  }
;
const example2 = wrapSource(source)
  .mm(val => console.log("mm:",1,val) || val + 20)
  .mm(val => console.log("mm:",2,val) || NOTHING)
  .mm(val => console.log("mm:",3,val) || val + 20)
;
example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
example2.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions come to mind for this case. However, if you are really looking for something like Haskell's maybe then Folktale (as user7128475 suggested) or [Sanctuary](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary) have Maybe implementations.

The first entails using `.filter` and `.defaultIfEmpty` however this only works if `oEmailInput$` is a 0 - 1 stream.

```
const oEmailValid$ = oEmailInput$
  .map(_catchInputCtrlValue)
  .map(_isStringNotEmpty)
  .filter(isValid => isValid) // or .filter(Boolean) 
  .map(...)
  .map(...)
  .map(...)
  .map(...)
  .defaultIfEmpty(false)
  .subscribe((predicate) => console.log(predicate))
```

This solution could also work inside of a flatMap if you wanted to apply it to a 0 - * stream.

```
const oEmailValid$ = oEmailInput$
  .map(_catchInputCtrlValue)
  .map(_isStringNotEmpty)
  .flatMap(isValid => Observable.of(isValid)
    .filter(Boolean) 
    .map(...)
    .map(...)
    .map(...)
    .map(...)
    .defaultIfEmpty(isValid)
  )
  .subscribe((predicate) => console.log(predicate))
```

A more general kind of solution would be to use flatMap again which works for 0 - * streams as well:

```
const oEmailValid$ = oEmailInput$
  .map(_catchInputCtrlValue)
  .flatMap(input => _isStringNotEmpty(input)
    ? Observable.of(input)
        .map(...)
        .map(...)
        .map(...)
        .map(...)
    : Observable.of(false)
  )
  .subscribe((predicate) => console.log(predicate))
```

Personally though, I don't think a stream is the best representation of that kind of problem. Streams best model actions\behavior with a single behavioral goal and right now the purpose of your original example is unclear to me and seems to have separate but equal branches. Streams should typically model how data moves through a series of desired actions to make up a single behavior. This is what I suspect Shuhei Kagawa was trying to get at. For instance I use a stream that represents a form that does the following:

```
onFormSubmit$
  .map(_validateData)
  .tap(console.log) // along the lines of your subscribe function
  .tap(showErrors)
  .tap(updateFormState)
  .filter(form => form.isValid)
  .subscribe(_postData)
```

and the result of `_validateData` would be a general shape like:

```
{
  isValid: true | false,
  fields: {
    email: string, // original input text
  },
  errors: [
    { name: "email", message: "Please enter a valid email address." },
  ],
}
```

This way steps like showErrors can map over the errors array and wont break if it's empty or require conditional testing.

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using only `map` , which means all validations happen synchronously, I would just write a function to handle all validations at once.

```
function validate(validators) {
  return input =>
    validators.every(validator => validator(input));
}

const oEmailValid$ = oEmailInput$
  .map(validate([
    _catchInputCtrlValue,
    _isStringNotEmpty,
    ...
  ]))
  .subscribe((predicate) => console.log(predicate));
```

I believe it’s nice to write pure functions as much as possible and use Stream or Monad-like things only when you really need them, like in Haskell.